# Flutter Firestore Convert Stream To Future

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, future

I have a firestore stream in flutter that I would instead like to be a future so that I can do pagination of requests. Currently I periodically increase the limit variable in the code below and reload the whole original stream plus new data. This is very irritating because every time the limit variable increases the widget (a listview) scrolls to the top. **I would like to ask how to convert the stream below into a future and how to place its contents into a list**. My purpose of doing so being that the contents of all the future calls will be accumulated in an list and my listview will be generated off of that array, hopefully without scrolling to the top every time.

My other reason for doing so is to save memory on the client device. When a user scrolls down I would like to remove items from the front of the list to save memory and reload them only if the user scrolls back up. **My project is a social-media application so I foresee users scrolling down indefinitely and using up all their phone memory. I am new to flutter so I would also like to ask if this memory usage is a valid concern.**

```
Stream<List<Memo>> getFeed(int limit) async* {
  yield* Firestore.instance
  .collection('memos')
  .where('followers', arrayContains: userid)
  .orderBy("date")
  .limit(limit) // TODO: add pagination of request
  // .startAfterDocument(null)
  .snapshots()
  .map(_snapshotToMemoList);
}
```

My Streamsubscription and listview builder code is as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Memo>>(
      stream: dbService( user: widget.user ).getFeed( streamLimit ),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Memo>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Loading...');
        default:
          if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
            return Text('EMPTY');
          }
          // streamSub.cancel();
          // return Text(snapshot.data[1].body);
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 600,
                child: Text(snapshot.data[index].body)
                );
            }
            );
      }
    },
  );
```

Lastly, my limit increasing function is

```
  void initState() {
    if (lastScrollPosition != null) _scrollController.jumpTo(lastScrollPosition);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      // print(maxScroll);
      final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      // print(currentScroll);
      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
        setState(() {
          lastScrollPosition = currentScroll;
          streamLimit += 1;
          print('increasing');
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: post your `ListView.builder` code - it it scrolls to the top, nost likely the problem is there, not in your stream

Comment: @pskink I have done so

Comment: @pskink How interesting; there is no output.

Comment: oh, sorry, it is `initState` method - it is called once

Comment: @pskink I see, that makes sense. Do you know a way to maintain the scroll position between rebuilds?

Comment: it is done automatically

Comment: @pskink Every time I scroll to the bottom the if statement at the end of the initstate is triggered and setState is called again and it jumps to the top. It does not appear to do so automatically.

Comment: This is the case even with my lastScrollPosition lines removed

Comment: @pskink, you're completely right, thank you. It seems my if/default/switch/case lines somehow cause the issue and without them the scroll position is maintained. This then raises the issue of error handling when I remove them however.

Comment: Oh, I see you covered even this in the link you posted. Thank you